# Informatica integration with Jenkins for deployment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to integrate Informatica Power Center & Jenkins to automate a deployment process. I am doing the deployment via pmrep command line utility provided by Informatica. It works perfectly fine manually.

I have created a free flow job in Jenkins where I am trying to connect the Informatica repository with a simple command.
Under Build --> Execute Windows Batch Command

```
"C:\Informatica\10.1.0\server\bin\pmrep.exe" connect -r REPO -d Domain -n Administrator -x myPassword
```

This is very simple project and it is getting failed with the below log:-

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\INFA_EXECUTE_QUERY>"C:\Informatica\10.1.0\server\bin\pmrep.exe" connect -r REPO -d Domain -n Administrator -x myPassword 
Informatica(r) PMREP, version [10.1.0], build [1205.0610], Windows 64-bit
Copyright (c) 1993-2016 Informatica LLC. All Rights Reserved.
See patents at https://www.informatica.com/legal/patents.html.
Invoked at Tue May 14 00:37:41 2019
Failed to execute connect.
Completed at Tue May 14 00:37:41 2019
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\INFA_EXECUTE_QUERY>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

However if I run the same command in command prompt on my laptop it works absolutely fine and able to connect to repository.

I have installed both Informatica server, client and Jenkins on my laptop but that shouldn't be the issue at all.

Comment: Try specifying host [-h] and port number [-o] in the connect command.

Comment: Maybe it's filesystem access problem: pmrep.exe tries to create a file named "pmrep.cnx" in the current directory. Check if the Jenkins user can write in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably lies in the users that the pmrep is run unser. You logged in and have certain priviledges to execute the pmrep.exe, to create the connection file pmrep.cnx, and, what is less obvios, Jenkins must have the same priveledges to connect to the repository as the user (settings in the Informatica administration console).